# How to tell HttpUnit to not fail for http status 4xx?

Tags: java, http-unit

In my unit test, I currently have this code:

```
int responseCode;
try {
    WebResponse response = new WebConversation().getResponse(new GetMethodWebRequest("http://myurl"));
    responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
} catch (HttpException e) {
    responseCode = e.getResponseCode();
}
assertThat(responseCode).isEqualTo(403);
```

This is quite verbose. I would prefer to use something like this:

```
WebConversation wc = new WebConversation();
wc.doNotFail(); // <= does not exist
assertThat(wc.getResponse(new GetMethodWebRequest("http://myurl")).getResponseCode()).isEqualTo(403);
```

How can I tell HttpUnit to not fail for http status 4xx?

Comment: What the documentation says ? Can you provide the `wc` type, I don't know `HttpUnit

Comment: You see, it was in the documentatino ;) I had a unplanned meeting ... couldn't check sooner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (for each test):

```
    wc.setExceptionsThrownOnErrorStatus(false);
```

or (for all tests):

```
    HttpUnitOptions.setExceptionsThrownOnScriptError(false);
```

Comment: Here is the [`WebConversation.setExceptionsThrownOnErrorStatus`](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/api/com/meterware/httpunit/WebClient.html#setExceptionsThrownOnErrorStatus%28boolean%29) documentation.